# calling Handlebars helper from another one

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way of calling a Handlebars helper from another one? I have a helper called `currency`:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper 'currency', (amount, options) ->
  rounded = Math.round amount * 100
  dec = rounded % 100
  whole = rounded / 100 - dec / 100
  decStr = dec.toString()
  "$#{whole}.#{decStr}#{if decStr.length < 2 then '0' else ''}"
```

and from the main one, `yourSavings` I wanted to call it:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper 'yourSavings', (amount, amount2, options) ->
  result = amount2 - amount
  result = if not result or result < 0 then 0 else result
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call arguments, 2
  args.unshift result
  Ember.Handlebars.helpers.currency.apply @, args
```

but had problems with resolving paths - I couldn't just pass in a number to the `currency`. Is it possible?